# How to make Android play music reliably, without chopping?

Tags: audio, music-player, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10, multitasking

When I try to play music on Android 2.3 (using various players, including PowerAmp) on Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 I get not reliable sound. Music pauses for a short time, for example, when:

- I press the power button (especially repeatedly) (`request_suspend_state: sleep;request_suspend_state: wakeup` in dmesg)
- When I see messages like `send sigkill to 15497 (ndroid.settings), adj 8, size 6428` in dmesg
- When some program reacts to changed screen orientation.
- When wifi connection gets established, when I force it to "reassociate"
- When I go to/from application from home screen (AWDLauncher), except of to/from WidgetLocker screen.
- When I enable/disable Airplane Mode.
- When the display is off (the most annoying)

When only really stable way to play music is to use StayAwake to force display on, turn off Wi-Fi, turn on Airplane Mode and don't switch applications. Starting CPU hogs like `while true; do true; done` does not affect chopping.

And it was playing more or less fine on Android 2.1.

"mediaserv" process (that writes to /dev/msm_pcm_out) has realtime io and scheduling priority, but sound is choppy anyway. If I start playing from console with `mplayer  -ao pcm:file=/dev/msm_pcm_out` the sound chop less (notably it does not get interrupted by power button / loading bunches of heavy processes), but still behave not normally when screen is off (even `ionice -c1 -p4 cat /dev/urandom > /dev/msm_pcm_out` is choppy)

When I start music A by usual way and music B using mplayer to /dev/msm_pcm_out (getting them mixed) music A chops more than usual and I usually hear B when A is in chop. When I turn off screen, both A and B chops in sync (stopping B leads to relatively more fluent playback of A this way).

How to play music on Android reliably in presence of background load? Should I report a bug somewhere?

**Update** Found a way of playing music. Inconvenient, but *without chopping*:

1. Start WakeLock in "CPU on, Screen Off, Keyboard off" mode
2. Use mplayer to play music bypassing Android:

```
ionice -c1 -n4  \
  schedtool -R -p 3 -e \
  mplayer -really-quiet \
        -af volume=-26 -quiet \
        -ao pcm:file=/dev/msm_pcm_out,nowaveheader \
    /mnt/sdcard/music/something.ogg
# (created script to start it easily, of course)
```

Plays without chopping no matter how much applications I start, what do with Wifi, orientation and airplane modes. Even with "powersave" cpufreq governor (everything very slow, but music plays fine). So the hardware have enough resources to play it.

**Update 2**
Looks like doing

```
for i in `pgrep ''`; do schedtool -D $i; done
```

i.e. "Set Idle priority for all processes" makes music play fine even when I {start programs,lock screen,rotate screen;it reconnects to other mobile network stations} at expense of some input lag in games. Don't know exactly why it happens.

Comment: What device do you have? Sounds like it's very resource constrained. Maybe a fast and light custom ROM would improve the performance.

Comment: Sony Ericsson Xperia X10. What does mean "resource constrained"? It should prioritise media over usual activities, allowing fluent playback independently on how much background load present. Also trying to cause load by explicitly using heavy applications hogging CPU and memory does not lead to choppy audio while just reassociating Wifi _always_ produces chop. Also it played more or less fine on Android 2.1

Comment: Music plays the same even I force powersave cpufreq governor (and CPU non-nice load is about 20% in this case). What resources can be short?

Comment: From what I can read from your additional comments: none. And I also have never heard that the X10 has a general problem with audio playback.

Comment: Including after update to Android 2.3?

Comment: Maybe the issues you're experiencing are localized to your device model. I'm running Android 2.3.6 on a Samsung YP-G70 and I experience no interruptions or chopping whatsoever no matter what I'm doing.

Comment: I have a very similar issue to this on a Nexus S running Jelly Bean 4.1.2. In my case the cause seems to be any background network access.

Comment: I feel that this it too localized, as its only affecting the OP's handset, what the OP failed to provide is **what background apps** are there running? Sound is not exactly fluid enough for the latency in Android versions < Gingerbread... and that is acknowledged and known.

Comment: There are many background programs, but I don't feel that any of them are high priority enough to disrupt sound. Low-prio fuss with starting and stopping BG processes just should not bother high-prio music playing.

Comment: Also the main question is that updating from 2.1 to 2.3 broke the sound (with approximately the same programs). /* Actually I've begun getting used to stoically ignoring the music choppiness... */

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off any applications or hardware that uses a lot of the phone's resources.  Turn off GPS, WIFI, Network Service, and dim the backlight.  Also shut down any other running applications than the ones you need for playing music.  If this still doesn't work your device may not have enough memory.

Comment: Looks like a general advice, not a solution/workaround to the bug. I tried various modes (described in question). OOM killer is only one of things that trigger the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Increase your `Audio Buffer` size.

I use PlayerPro Music Player with its DSP pack. DSP pack allows me to adjust audio buffer size. I never needed to use this feature, but it will help you.

You can also find other music players to support this feature. The key is `Audio Buffer`.

Alternatively, you can reduce music quality as well as system load.

Comment: At least setting maximum buffer size in Mixzing player does not help.

Comment: "reduce music quality as well as system load" -> workaround, not fix. I already have hacky workarounds (see "Updates")